# Enumerating short versus long column names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA views on DB2 for IBM i

Tags: db2-midrange

On the IBM i (as/400) you can have short and long column names on a table. The short names are listed in the `SYSTEM_COLUMN_NAME` field of `QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS` and the ODBC/JDBC `SQLCOLUMNS` view. Is it possible to get these short column names from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA view or is it not possible since its not a feature supported in most RDBMSes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA does not contain the long column names.